# PHP checkbox always returns on

Tags: php, html

I have this checkbox in my form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="private" id="private" />
```

When I submit my form, the checkbox always returns on, even when I didn't check it.

```
echo $_POST['private'] //result is always returns on

$private = isset($_POST['private']) ? 1 : 0; //result is 1 always
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the input a value and check that:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="private" id="private" value="1"/>

$private = isset($_POST['private']) && $_POST['private'] == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I tried adding a value, still the same issue, when I have my checkbox unchecked it returns 1

Comment: And when I have it checked, it still returns 1

Comment: can you update your question with what you tried when giving the input a value

Answer (score 0):

`isset($_POST['private'])` will always return true, because `$_POST['private']` is exists.

Add value to checkbox `<input type="checkbox" name="private" id="private" value="1" />` and use `$private = $_POST['private'] ? 1 : 0;` or if you are use PHP 7+ `$private = $_POST['private'] ?? 0;`

Comment: Still returns 1 regardless.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit an HTML form, the `$_POST['input_name']` for checkbox elements are always set, so your `isset($_POST['private'])` always returns true.

You should instead be directly checking the value of the checkbox elemenet like so:

```
$private = $_POST['private'];
```

This will give you your desired result, if the checkbox is checked, `$private` will equal 1, otherwise 0.

Comment: Still returns 1